# Spring Security - multiple frame options

Tags: iframe, spring-security

I have two web-applications. The first one displays the second one in an iFrame. Both applications are additionally accessible on their own through intranet and internet.

Now i have the following security settings in the http-element of my security settings:

```
<headers>
    <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
    <frame-options policy="ALLOW-FROM" strategy="whitelist" value="https://www.myurl.com" />
</headers>
```

The access through the intranet works fine, the frame content is loaded. Through the internet the content cannot be loaded and the frame shows the error "This content cannot be displayed in a frame."

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. No special headers must be set. If I remove the security settings for the header completely, it works.